# Listview Custom Layout Multiple Choice

Tags: android, xml, listview, simplecursoradapter

I would like to create a listview that allows multiple choice. The typical solutions is to get a cursor and use the SimpleCursorAdapter.

```
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, cur2, cols2, views2);
```

I am able to get this working when using the `R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`. I get the checkmarks to work when multiple items are selected.

So I decided to try it with a custom made layout. Here is the XML code for my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lookup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hasphone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

So here is my issue. The layout is inflated fine using the same code and setting the ChoiceMode to multiple on my listview. The data from the cursor is populated fine.

However, the issue I have is that the checkmarks do not show up as selected (a check in the box) when I click on the item. Is there something I am missing that would not involve creating a custom adapter?

---

```
l2.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

l2 is my listview.

Comment: Do you want it to happen when you click on the list item, or when you click on the checkbox in the list item?

Comment: I would prefer it to happen when I click the list item. If you know how to do both, I would not mind knowing how to do it both ways. Thx

Comment: With a CheckedTextView you can't do both, I was thinking TextView and Checkbox.  Anyway, you have LinearLayout called out twice... is your file actually like that?  If it is, remove that first LinearLayout callout and see what happens.

Comment: No it is not I will update the post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How did you set the choice mode to multiple?  (I've been playing around and so far, that not being set is the ony thing that makes it not work for me).

Comment: Exactly how I do it.  I'm out of ideas other than the possible hack I posted below.  :/

Comment: I don't give up easy.  Found a solution for you (and the cause too),  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not up on CheckedTextView... from my understanding, it should toggle the check when you click the line.

I suppose you could try and force it like this:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {  
    CheckedTextView chkTxt = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.CheckedTextView1); 
    chkTxt.toggle(); 
}
```

Note this would be a hack and you should really find the root problem, but it might get you going in the meantime.

**EDIT**

After much googling, I found the issue... the root of the row layout needs to be checkable to use CheckedTextView, and a LinearLayout is not.

More googling found a solution... override the LinearLayout class.

Instructions/code [here](http://tokudu.com/2010/android-checkable-linear-layout/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with *"the issue I have is that the checkmarks do not show up as selected"* is because of your wrong layout. It should be without LinearLayout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lookup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hasphone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" />
```

Then the SimpleCursorAdapter can set properly your "checkedTextView1" (with visible effect).

In my case I used the ArrayAdapter and it worked.

```
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.category_layout,
                    R.id.category_checkedText, this.categories));
```